# recipe for target 'all' failed on Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

1) Program **works** well if I type each command on Terminal by gcc -o `file1 file1.c && gcc file2.c -lm -o file2`, and then `./file1 someArgs ./file2 someArgs`

2) Also **works** if I type in Terminal: make rst and make res

3) **Not working** by typing `make` in Terminal

Makefile:

```
all:
    check

default:
    check

clean:
    rm -rf file1 file2

rst:
    gcc -o file1 file1.c && gcc file2.c -lm -o file2

res:
    ./file1 someArgs ./file2 someArgs

check:
    make clean
    make rst
    make res
```

Also tried:

```
all:
    check

default:
    check

clean:
    rm -rf file1 file2

rst:
    gcc -o file1 file1.c && gcc file2.c -lm -o file2

res:
    ./file1 someArgs ./file2 someArgs

check:
    clean
    rst
    res
```

And some other combinations with or without `make`. All same error:

```
make: check: Command not found
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first target `all` is trying to run a command called `check` (and so is the target `default`). I think you want the command `make` to behave the same as the command `make check` and to perform the actions of the target called `check` in the Makefile. In that case, add it as a dependency like this:

```
all: check

default: check

clean:
    rm -rf file1 file2

rst:
    gcc -o file1 file1.c && gcc file2.c -lm -o file2

res:
    ./file1 someArgs ./file2 someArgs

check:
    make clean
    make rst
    make res
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have some confusion between the prerequisites of a make rule and its recipe.  The prerequisites go on the same line as the target name; the recipe goes on the next tab-indented line or lines.  Thus, for example, this rule ...

```
all:
    check
```

... says that target 'all' has no prerequisites (so it is always considered out of date), and that the recipe for building it is to run a *command* `check`.  What you appear actually to want is to build the target named 'check', which you can cause to happen by making 'check' a prerequisite of 'all':

```
all: check
```

More generally, you seem to be approaching the makefile as if it were a *program* with multiple entry points, but it is much better viewed as a set of rules that `make` can use to build things.  Thus, it is conventional and desirable for rules that actually build a file to specify the built file as a target.  Moreover, to use the full power of `make`, you should express the proper prerequisites for those and other rules.  For example:

```
./file1: file1.c
    gcc -o file1 file1.c

./file2: file2.c
    gcc file2.c -lm -o file2

res: ./file1 ./file2
    ./file1 someArgs ./file2 someArgs
```

If you do that correctly then you don't need hacks such as removing and rebuilding the programs every time -- `make` will figure out whether they are out of date, and will rebuild them if and when it needs to do.

Comment: Note, by the way, that the lines of each `make` recipe *must* each start with a tab character, which is difficult to input into a web form such as the one into which an SO answer needs to be typed.  If you cut & paste my sample code you will likely need to correct the indentation.

Comment: fantastic answer, gave the "check" to the other guy b/c he's slightly faster